# In C#, how is it that two text fields can have the same property name?

Tags: c#

I'm making changes to a solution built by the person who had my position before me and I'm trying to reproduce something he did but am having issues.

This solution has two forms: Reports Entry and Reports Review. All his property names for these text fields have the same name (i.e., txtProduct appears on both the Reports Entry and Reports Review forms.) I am trying to add a new text field called txtComments however, after I've created this field in one of the forms and try to add the same field to the other, it is telling me the property value is not valid: txtComments is already in use by another component.

How can I work around this?

---

Thank you for your responses. It turned out to be two text fields on top of one another with the same name.

Comment: Having two fields with identical names in different unrelated forms should be OK. Do you have another component in the form called `txtComments` preventing you from adding a duplicate?

Comment: This is unlikely. Can you check your code again?

Comment: you will have to use a different name.

Comment: And these are on two different forms? So there in two different classes? If this is the case there should be absolutely no problem adding a new TextBox to a separate form that has the same name.

Comment: It of course may not be a text box, but perhaps a label .. badly named.

Comment: Check the second form (the one that would not let you use the name), it already has something else by that name.